# Bugsnag for multiple bundles in react native

Tags: react-native, bugsnag

I have a react native application which consist of multiple bundles.I am unable to add the multiple source-map on bugsnag due to which error are not getting shown properly. How can i upload multiple source-maps or can support the multiple bundles in react native.